# Configuring WCF endpoint to enable both WebScript and Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, session

In fear of asking a question which has already been saturated on Stack Overflow, I have been scrolling through possible solutions and am none the wiser as how to achieve what I want to achieve, if it is indeed possible, or whether I have designed my system incorrectly.

This question is not just about finding a solution, but to explain some of WCF’s complexities (and misunderstandings) when configuring/customising different endpoints.

**A Typical Scenario**: *A web-based checkout system where the customer can alter attributes such as qty or size of the product within their basket via making javascript calls back to the server. The server has to be aware of who the user is, so having a session available seems an ideal solution.*

WCF definitely seems the way to go, as this scenario can be extended at a future date to support another end-point, such as a mobile app or other service. (Outside the scope of my question, but verifying that I would like to use WCF against a legacy .Net Web Service)

My problem with the above is configuring the endpoints / bindings.

- **webHttpBinding** – This is used so that web scripts can access the service (ie Javascript from a webpage). However it does not support sessions
- **wsHttpBinding** – This supports sessions but not web scripts.

I've played around with various configurations. It seems that I need a combination of the above bindings, or maybe to create a custom binding which supports these elements? If so, are there any nice resources on how to do so? I've tried creating a custom binding and failed miserably!

I've read various comments on other questions that suggest you shouldn't use Sessions via web scripts, that WCF doesn't support it, or that the system being implemented has been incorrectly designed. Firstly, WebServices support this so I find it hard to believe that WCF doesn't, especially as it supports both webscripts and sessions individually (but not together? Out the box maybe...). If I were to use something other than sessions, it would have to be a token based system so that the user can be identified, but surely this is effectively what a session is? I can build this, but it seems like recreating the wheel.

Here is the configuration within my Web.Config. I have setup 3 endpoints to play with; one basic, one supporting sessions and the other supporting webscripts. (The address for the webHttpBinding endpoint is blank, as the service returns an error when in debug mode – I’ve seen this stated by several people too)

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomerServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
          <!--<webHttp />-->
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebScript">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="CustomerService">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding"
          contract="CustomerService" />
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsConfig"
          contract="CustomerService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="CustomerServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webConfig" contract="CustomerService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"></security>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647  "/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsConfig" transactionFlow="true">
          <security mode="None" />
          <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webConfig">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And this is my service interface, showing that I have set the SessionMode to Allow, and GetSession() which returns the current session id, or null if sessions are unavailable.

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "", ConfigurationName = "CustomerService", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface ICustomerService
{
  [OperationContract()]
  [WebGet()]
  bool UpdateBasketItem(int index, int productId, int qty, int attribSize);

  [OperationContract()]
  [WebGet()]
  string GetSession();
}
```

**So my long winded question is this..** Can I configure an endpoint to have webscript enabled so that I can access the service via javascript, and also sessions enabled at the same time? I have tested the endpoints individually via the WCF Test Client to see that the 'ws' endpoint does have sessions, and that the blank endpoint using webHttpBinding does not have sessions but is callable from Javascript.

I understand that there may not be an 'out of the box' binding for this, so do I need to create a custom binding, or can I somehow morph the above two endpoints by using a sprinkle of configuration magic?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a service technology that can easily be accessed through JavaScript I would strongly consider Asp.Net WEB API instead. It's a great framework form creating web apis.

It's much more accessible than wcf from a client side perspective and you can leverage standard asp.net concepts. Cookies, Session, Cache etc.

I believe web api was even created in response to the difficulty of doing this in wcf.

I would only consider wcf if you need SOAP support.

Comment: That does look like a possible route that I've not considered, and time has long become my enemy, so I may end up taking that route!

Comment: I'm still a sucker for finding out where I'm going wrong with a problem ;)